# How do I change the default web hosting provider name of my ip address?

Tags: apache, azure, webserver, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

When I visit https://www.whoishostingthis.com/ and type in my IP address, I get this information:

```
Hosting Provider:
Microsoft Azure

Owner Details:
Whois Record

IP Address:
(my web server's ip address)

Server Location:
Des Moines, US
```

Is it possible to change the default name of the hosting provider (Microsoft Apache) to my own? if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't - it's not some field you can specify on your website. It's being determined based on where it is hosted, in this case Azure.

This is most likely done by looking up the DNS entry for your site, then the IP returned is checked against ranges of IPs registered with the various hosting providers

The only way to change this is to move your site to a different hosting provider

Comment: Could I change my hosting provider's name or make my own hosting provider?

Comment: No, this is all completely outside of your control